# Jetpack Compose TextField capture keyboard Enter-input

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-compose-textfield

From what I understand, there is an API for the Jetpack Compose Textfield for capturing Keyboard actions but I don't know what of this APIs that can capture the Enter-Input

The use-case of this capturing enter input is to enable to  click Enter and try to go to the next TextField and keeping while keeping the keyboard open

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = username.value,
    onValueChange = {
        username.value = it
        },
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = {},
        onGo = {},
        onNext = {},
        onPrevious ={},
        onSearch ={},
        onSend = {}
        )
)
```

Comment: Additional question: I can't seem to have a physical keyboard do an IME action. I need it to run my onDone / onSubmit after a physical keyboard presses enter, but instead it just creates a new line.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
val (focusRequester) = FocusRequester.createRefs()

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    singleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
            true
        }
        false
    }
)

TextField(
    value = text2,
    onValueChange = {
        text2 = it
    },
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
)
```

Comment: thanks for this, I've tried adding this to the 2nd textfield
`singleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
            true
        }
        false
    }` 
to the second textfield and use `focusRequester.freeFocus()` instead but somehow it didn't remove the focus on the 2nd textfield any idea on this?

Comment: @ArcRuler Use `val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current` 
 and in the `Modifier.onKeyEvent` of the 2nd field: `focusManager.clearFocus()`

Comment: How would I run an IME action there? A physical keyboard enter does not trigger any IME action, and I need it to run onDone.

Comment: @dessalines I guess this is Done button on on-screen keyboard.

GabrieleMariotti I guess, did you miss "else" before "false"?

Comment: What's the point for onValueChange?

Comment: How to make TextField don't lose focus after Enter?

Comment: Looks like `singleLine = true` and `true` in `onKeyEvent` don't help: newline is added to output variable.