# Android Jetpack Compose: Listen to user's keyboard input not working with Enter key

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to execute a function upon Enter Key pressed on soft keyboard and I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67898610/13892944) `Modifier.onKeyEvent{}` to listen to user input on soft keyboard in general.

However, this doesn't work with Enter key(especially 'Done' key on number pad).

My soft keyboard looks like this

[image]

with this option below in TextField

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
```

when I print logs on any key pressed, all other keys press are recognized but those 'Done' and '.-' keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle it with [`keyboardActions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/KeyboardActions) text field argument:

```
TextField(
    value = text, onValueChange = { text = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
    ),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
        println("done")
    })
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day. but I am just curious where you got this solution? I wasn't able to find it anywhere. could you leave me a link related to this?

Comment: @foseja I've added link to documentation. Also you can check out [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/android-keyboard-handling-using-jetpack-compose-c478f7afaae0)

Answer (score 1):

The enter key is special.  Especially when it's not an enter key, but a Done button or similar.  Instead of sending a commitText, it send it via the OnEditorActionListener of the view.  You need to set an OnEditorActionListener and handle the case in that.