# How to make TextField clear the text when ENTER is pressed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is my TextField;

```
@Composable
fun AppSearchBar() {
    val appSearchViewModel: AppSearchViewModel by lazy {
        AppSearchViewModel.ViewModelProvider.provideAppSearchViewModel()
    }
    val searchText by appSearchViewModel.searchText.collectAsState()

    TextField(
        value = searchText,
        leadingIcon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search, contentDescription = null) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .requiredHeight(APP_SEARCH_BAR_HEIGHT)
            .padding(MODIFIER_PADDING_10),
        onValueChange = { appSearchViewModel.onSearchTextChange(it) },
        placeholder = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.app_drawer_search)) },
        shape = CircleShape,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = {
                appSearchViewModel.onSearchTextClear()
            }
        ),
        singleLine = true
    )
}
```

When i press ENTER it makes a new line in the input bar instead of clearing the text. I've tried both:

```
singleLine = true
```

and:

```
maxLines = 1
```

but it always makes a new line. I've also tried changing the imeAction to Search and Go to no avail.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you talking about HW keyboard or soft? Because the code provided seems to work for me as is - even when I remove `maxLines`/`singleLine`.  The first step I would try is to move `viewModel` out of the function and pass just `value` and `onChange`,`onDone` lambdas.

Comment: @TheLibrarian The issue is for HW keyboard, I just checked and soft keyboard works for me too. I've put the the viewModel here as to only trigger recomposition of that composable not the whole container element

Comment: Then I think you have the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897100/jetpack-compose-textfield-capture-keyboard-enter-input

Comment: I was able to use .onKeyEvent to detect Enter and clear the text, but it would also quickly make a new line and then clear the input. So I made a workaround where I simply look for "\n" in a string that gets passed inside the appSearchViewModel.onSearchTextChange(it) and clear the text if I find it.

Comment: Are you returning false in the onKeyEvent? true for consuming event, false for not. Also in which action are you doing this? DOWN or UP?